# More popup video when i press a button

Tags: javascript, button, video, popup

Sorry for my english i use google translate!

I want more button to bring popup with different video but i don t know how to make the second button
If you can help me on the same code that I had put below, I would be very happy

```js
const Module = document.querySelector('.mod')
const openModule = document.querySelector('.openbuton')
const closeModule = document.querySelector('.closebuton')


openModule.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Module.showModal();

})


closeModule.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Module.close();

})

var vid = document.getElementById("video")

function pauseVid() {
  vid.pause();
}

function loadVid() {
  vid.load();
  vid.play();
}
```

```css
.mod {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}

.mod::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#video {
  border: 2px solid wheat;
  ;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="loadVid()" class="openbuton">apasa ma</button>
<dialog class="mod">
  <video id="video" src="/video/Hacksaw Ridge video.mp4"></video>
  <button onclick="pauseVid()" class="closebuton">nu ma apasa</button>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the Popup Open Code into a function, so it can be reused & then add it to the listener of both the buttons.

Also, you can call the `loadVid` & `pauseVid` functions inside listeners instead of calling them separately in HTML.

Edit:

So, in order to have different buttons load different videos, we need to have an array with video URLs & the buttons need to have a data attribute that will identify their respective `ID`. Using this ID on Click we can load the desired video.

```js
const Module = document.querySelector('.mod')

const openModule = document.querySelector('.openbuton')
const otherButton = document.querySelector(".otherBtn");
const thirdButton = document.querySelector(".thirdBtn");

const closeModule = document.querySelector('.closebuton')

const videoSources = [
  "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",
  "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4",
  "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
];

function openModal(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  const src = videoSources[id];
  loadVid(src);

  Module.showModal();
}


openModule.addEventListener('click', openModal);
otherButton.addEventListener('click', openModal);
thirdButton.addEventListener('click', openModal);


closeModule.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Module.close();
  pauseVid();
})

var vid = document.getElementById("video")

function pauseVid() {
  vid.pause();
}

function loadVid(videoSrc) {
  vid.setAttribute('src', videoSrc);
  vid.load();
  vid.play();
}
```

```css
.mod {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}

.mod::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#video {
  border: 2px solid wheat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Data Attribute storing the Video ID -->
<button class="openbuton" data-id="0">apasa ma</button>
<!-- Data Attribute storing the Video ID -->
<button class="otherBtn" data-id="1">Second Video</button>
<!-- Data Attribute storing the Video ID -->
<button class="thirdBtn" data-id="2">Third Video</button>


<dialog class="mod">
  <video id="video"></video>
  <button class="closebuton">nu ma apasa</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but I want to put many buttons with different videos

Comment: So you want to load different buttons that will load & play different videos?

Comment: Yes!But with the same format as pop up

Comment: @Catalin I've made some Edits. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: I don't know what to do on "Data Attribute storing the Video ID"!I need just to make a<video id='example' src=lalalala></video>or create a new <dialog> or a div and bring <video id='example' src=lalalala></video> in?Sorry for wasting your time!!

Comment: You just need to create an array of all the video URLs & using the data attribute of the buttons, you can change the source of the video element. You don't need to have multiple video or dialog elements. If you see in my code in data attribute, I'm storing the Video array index as ID.

Comment: The code works now but I have an error that I don't know how to solve. sometimes I press the button and a dialog appears but not the video and in the console it says:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.And in src instead of the URL of the video appear src='undefined'

Comment: Check if you are passing the correct ID inData Attribute. Because an array would return `undefined` if you try to access an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: It's fair because it works sometimes! data-id='0'